# Multiple jQuery versions: Apply plugin to only one of them

Tags: jquery

I'm in the situation of having multiple versions of jQuery on a site. Now, there's a jQuery plugin I'd like to apply to `jQuery_1_0_0`, instead of `jQuery`.

How can I do that without touching the plugins source code?

Comment: _“I'm in the situation of having multiple versions of jQuery on a site.”_ – that’s bad. That’s the _real_ problem that you should get fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the plugin directly after the version of jquery you want it to affect.

```
<script src="jquery.1.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.plugin.req.1.0.0.js"></script>
```

assuming you're using `$.noConflict` rather than modifying `jquery.1.0.0.js` directly.

Comment: Then make sure to `$.noConflict` after including the other jQuery.